# Shows Touch On Highlight for UIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uiimage

The UIButton has a cool attribute that is called "Shows Touch On Highlight" that allows me to tell the user "you touched this button".

Is there any way I can implement this for a UIImage? I want the user to see the point touched inside the UIImage.

Comment: Can't you just use a UIButton of the size of your image and assign your image to the custom button?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a little trick. make a transparent button above UIImageView. so must set a UIImageView userInteractionEnabled true bec default false. as follows:

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIButton *clearButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
clearButton.frame = imageView.frame;
clearButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
[clearButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[imageView addSubView:clearButton];
```

other trick, create a transparent button, and set image your want.

```
UIButton *clearButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
clearButton.frame = CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>);
clearButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
[clearButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[clearButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Won't I loose the interaction with the UIImage though?

Comment: Right now I color in red the parts I touch inside the UIImage

Comment: Have you run the above code? I think you will have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't in same way as in `UIButton`, but you can use `UIButton` of type custom, instead to solve it for you.

Another help with UIImageView is setting it's Highlight image, but still you have to work for effect.